# Why there are twice “query rollback” every time when I query

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

sql.log

```
2022-12-09T10:46:30.814252Z   877 Query SELECT flag.id AS flag_id, flag.code AS flag_code, flag.isused AS flag_isused, flag.user_id AS flag_user_id
FROM flag
WHERE flag.code = '000027'
LIMIT 1
2022-12-09T10:46:30.815296Z   877 Query ROLLBACK
2022-12-09T10:46:30.815512Z   877 Query ROLLBACK
```

code

```py
def exchange_code():
    code =  request.json.get('code')
    flag = db.session.query(Flag).filter_by(code=code).first()
    return flag.id
```

I'm using `SQLAlchemy==1.4.44` and `Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.5.1`

i just want figure out why there twice "Query  ROLLBACK" every time i query.

Comment: Are you running your code in some kind of framework (for example Flask or Django)? If so, which one?

Comment: Most likely, the first ROLLBACK is done explicitly by SQLAlchemy and the second ROLLBACK is done automatically by the DBAPI layer when the connection is closed (or released back to the connection pool).

Comment: @snakecharmerb  Yes, I use Flask